# Postgres Error: must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm a novice when it comes to Postgres, and I realize similar questions have been asked before, however, I'm struggling to make this query work:

```
SELECT    p_search.id, count(kia.image_id) AS count
FROM      (SELECT id,
                  keyword,
                  to_tsvector('english',keyword) AS tskw
          FROM keyword) AS p_search
LEFT JOIN keyword_image_assoc AS kia 
ON        kia.keyword_id = p_search.id
WHERE     p_search.tskw @@ plainto_tsquery('english','resident life')
OR        p_search.tskw @@ plainto_tsquery('english','wofford')
GROUP BY  kia.image_id
ORDER BY  count desc
```

For context, I have three tables:

- `image` which has an `id` as the primary key
- `keyword` which has `id` as the primary key and `keyword` which is a string representing a keyword
- `keyword_image_assoc` which has an `id`, `image_id` and `keyword_id` which is used to associate images and keywords canonically.

If I add `p_search.id` to the `GROUP BY` clause, the results aren't correct - `count` is always 1. Is there a way to group the results so the `image_id`s have the count of the number of matching keywords?

I'm looking for two columns `count` - the number of matching keywords and `image_id` the id of the corresponding image. Thanks!

Comment: Try GROUP BY p_search.id instead. (remove p_search.id)

Comment: @EdgarAllanBayron That does kind of the opposite that i need - it returns a count of images per keyword; i need keywords per image...

Comment: Change `p_search.id` by `kia.image_id`

Comment: `SELECT kia.image_id, count(*) AS count ... GROUP BY kia.image_id`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at Postgres docs about [GROUP BY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY):

> When **GROUP BY** is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it is not valid for the **SELECT** list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions or when the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column.

According to this you cannot reference a field on the SELECT statement if it doesn't appear on the GROUP BY clause or without using an aggregated function.

In your example, you're referencing `p_search.id` but it doesn't appear on the GROUP BY clause. You could try to change it by `kia.image_id`